# Creating a scratchy ticket

Tags: javascript, interaction

Looking to create a scrathie ticket effect in javascript where a block is presented and you  with the mouse) click and drag to reveal the image behind

Am determined not to use Flash

This is the best I could find so far in terms of an example script
http://www.siteexperts.com/tips/styles/ts37/page1.asp

Anyone know of a better more 'scratch-like' example with code?

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to overlay a `canvas` over something, and scratch away the position of the mouse pointer.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/cWzJu/).

Comment: would that be compatible with ie7, ie8? I tried the link but there was no scratching interaction, just the blank canvas, was there meant to be?